# What does rtype mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When I do some code tests, there are some comments below the solution function like this:

```
"""
:type x: int
:rtype: int
"""
```

`x` is my only input, so what does *rtype* stand for?

Comment: I'd guess it stands for "return type" (though it should be described in the doc of whatever tool is reading this docstring)

Comment: Is this specific to leetcode?

Answer (score 15):

To avoid confusion:

```
type:    Type of a parameter.
vartype: Type of a variable. 
rtype:   Return type.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the abbreviation for "return type".

See the [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists) for more information on field names and examples.

Answer (score -1):

:type: is the datatype of parameter(s) you're passing and :rtype: is the datatype of the return value.
Docstrings help us tell what are the datatypes of parameters and the return value

Here is an example code:

```
# with docstrings
def multiply(a, b):
    """:type a: int
       :type b: int
       :rtype: int
    """
    return a * b
```

However, there is a newer way to do the same.
It is called Type Hinting in python. It was introduced in python3.5.
Remember, we are doing the same thing, it is like inline commenting, your intention remains the same

```
# with type hinting
def multiply(a : int, b : int) -> int:
    return a * b
```

This does the job in fewer lines :)
Type hinting python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html